# Can't save base64 jpg in python

Tags: python, base64

I have a base64 jpg that I want to save in my project folder.
I tried with

```
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(img.decode('base64'))
```

but image.jpg is 0KB.
The img is something like
`img= '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/...'`

How can I solve the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a `.decode()`, is suppose the image string is already bytes-encoded. In this case you could use a code like this:

```
import base64
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.decodebytes(img))
```

`.decodebytes()` takes a byte-encoded base64 string and turns it back into image bytes you can then write to file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting 0KB

Comment: @Frapple looks like something is wrong with your base64 bytes string. You could look at this (https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/#decodingbinarydatawithpython) example and try to figure out, what's wrong with your code

Comment: ok, I managed the problem: I was missing the encode('utf-8') :)