# How to recover a .jpg image from a encoded GMail attachment in Python

Tags: python, base64, gmail-api

I'm using the GMail API in Python.
I am succesfully downloading the attachment of an email using

```
attachment = service.users().messages().attachments().get(userId='me', messageId = msg_id, id=attachment_id).execute()
```

From this I can recover the data and decode it using

```
data = attachement['data']
decoded_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, I do not understand how to recover the .jpg from this string.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very straightforward.
First two functions from 2 different libraries must be imported:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
```

Then the image can be saved using these two functions:

```
im = Image.open(BytesIO(decoded_data))
im.save('attachement', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: Why don't you just write the binary data data directly to a file?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027622/7329832